# Running a random select and timer function together in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, bots

I'm currently working on a twitter bot with javascript, node and the twit package. I have set up a timer and a random select function, so my aim is that the bot tweets every 60sec and chooses a random sentence from my array. When I test both bits alone (the timer OR the random function) they work but for some reason I can't make them work in conjunction.
I tried to declare a variable for the getRandomSentence() function (like var tweet = getRandomSentence(tweet)) but then I would get this error  return sentences[index];
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined

The code like I've uploaded it now runs but the timer doesn't seem to work.

```js
// timer
setInterval(getRandomSentence, 1000*60)

// random
  var sentences = [

  'sentence1',

  'sentence2',

  'sentence3.',

  'sentence4',

  'sentence5',

  'sentence6'

    ],
    maxSentences = sentences.length;

    function getRandomSentence() {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxSentences - 1));
        return sentences[index];
    }

//  tweets
//
T.post('statuses/update', { status: getRandomSentence()}, tweeted);

function tweeted (err, data, response) {
if (err) {
 console.log(err);
}
else {
 console.log("It works.");
 }
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me here! I'm still an absolute newbie.

Comment: The error is pretty clear - `T is not defined`

Comment: @JamesHill I think they've just not included the code for the T. Is there a syntax error after the sentences array? What's the comma doing there?

Comment: He's declaring an array and int inline.  It's fine.  Not the most readable way to do it, but it's not the issue.

Comment: @Aaron Of course haha. Indentation threw me

Comment: @JamesHill The T is not the problem, the problem is that setInterval and my getRandomSentence function don't work together and I've got no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Hi have made some changes to the code. This works to console log a random sentence to tweet every 60 seconds:

```
var sentences = [
    'sentence1',
    'sentence2',
    'sentence3',
    'sentence4',
    'sentence5',
    'sentence6'
];
var maxSentences = sentences.length;

var sentenceToTweet = '';

function getRandomSentence() {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxSentences - 1));

    sentenceToTweet = sentences[index];

    console.log(sentenceToTweet);

    setTimeout(getRandomSentence, 1000 * 60);
}

getRandomSentence();
```

Comment: thanks for the input, that sounds similar to my approach of setting var tweet = getRandomSentence(tweet); and it didn't throw an error but unfortunately it didn't make the timer work either.

Comment: If you want it to tweet every 60 seconds then you will also have to post your tweet within the interval function too.

Comment: I have updated my answer to select the random sentence and log it to the console every 60 seconds.